# Slackware scripts started at boot time need env vars from /etc/profile.d/* to be set

Tags: environment-variables, slackware, rc.local

Hey, I have this problem, that scripts started at boot time from rc.local don't have environment variables (defined at /etc/profile.d/*) set at the time of their startup. What should I do ?

---

"su - lisak -c /opt/atlassian-jira-enterprise-4.1.1-standalone/bin/startup.sh"

"su - lisak -c /opt/aaa2/at-22/bin/startup.sh"

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The scripts at `/etc/profile.d/*` are executed in their own shells rather than sourced so the environment variables they set are not available anyway.What variables do you need? Can you make use of `/etc/environment`? Can you write the variables into a file in a `var=value` format from the appropriate scripts and source that file in your `rc.local` scripts?</strike>

This is from the Bash man page. You may find it helpful.

> When  bash  is  started  non-interactively,  to run a shell script, for
>          example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands
>          its  value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name
>          of a file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the  following  com‐
>          mand were executed:
>                 if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
>          but  the  value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file
>          name.

The Bourne shell similarly uses the `ENV` variable.

Comment: I don't want to do such workarounds, if I do this often I wouldn't do anything but administration :-)

Comment: /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/* are accessed for each login shell...and I'm starting the script by su, which doesn't start a login shell I suppose...

Comment: I meant that you should add code that automates the creation of the variable-holding file. Anyway, I was think about this backwards. `rc.local` is run at boot time, but the files in `profile.d` are executed at user login time. You're trying to mix two different worlds - system boot and user login.

Comment: I know that the proper way of doing it would be via /etc/bashrc which is loaded for each interactive shell start. .. btw those $BASH_ENV or $ENV are not visible to users, are they....root doesn't see them...is it something under the hood ?

Comment: Those variables aren't set by default. You set them, for example, in a script that calls another or on the command line of a call to a script. `BASH_ENV=foo /path/to/bar` (on one line, this sets the variable for the environment of "bar").

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the su manpage (Slackware 13.1):

```
       -, -l, --login
       Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had
       the user logged in directly.

       When - is used, it must be specified as the last su option. The
       other forms (-l and --login) do not have this restriction.
```

In your example, you don't specify - as the last su option. Try doing that or using an alternate argument.

Comment: you are maybe right, but I can't figure out how it would look like... su - lisak -c /opt/aaa2/at-22/bin/startup.sh  is the only order of arguments that is actually possible

Comment: Btw where do you get this manpage from, the mine doesn't mention anything you pasted

Comment: I just typed man su in Slackware 13.1

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to source /etc/profile.d/*.sh or run /etc/profile from rc.local cause I don't want to duplicate configuration for boot time scripts and scripts started from login shell...

NOTE: I don't know what might be the consequences of running /etc/profile from rc.local ...so the best way would be sourcing them at rc.local from /etc/profile.d/*.sh

---

AKA:  for file in /etc/profile.d/*; do source $file; done

---

ALTERNATIVE:  echo ". /etc/profile" >> $HOME/.bashrc     - for single user